# Who can select the proper answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I have come across people answering questions. But some answers may not be understood by the person who asked it even though that can be the correct answer.

In that situation, who is going to mark it as 'Answered'? I think nobody except the person who asked can tick it.

Comment: "I think nobody except the person who answered can tick it." - do you actually mean "nobody except the person who *asked* can tick it

Comment: @JoseK sorry for the typo.... Correct it is what you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think nobody except the person who answered can tick it.

This is correct. The only person who can accept answers is the person who asked the question. They are the only person who will ever be able to tick or untick the green checkmark.

However, other members of the community can *vote* on answers—either up or down—and with the default sort order, answers that have a higher score are shown on top. This gives the community the ability to "rank" answers in terms of their accuracy and usefulness, even though they cannot choose or alter the accepted answer.

> But some answers may not understand the person who asked it even though that can be the correct answer.

This is generally indicative of a serious problem with the question. If someone took the time to read it and compose an answer, but *still* didn't understand what was being asked, the question is probably unclear and desperately in need of editing.

You should not blame the answerers for misunderstanding a poorly-asked question.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've taken to understand **this** question. The OP's wording is confusing - "But some answers may not understand the person who asked it even though that can be the correct answer." I think he means to say the questioner might not understand or recognize the correct answer, but got his words switched round

Comment: This particular case applies to answers for concepts.In this situation, if the person does not have enough understanding about it, then the question will be left unanswered.However, the community may have up voted it.If that is the case,what is the use of 'Answer' button.

Comment: The person who asked the question gets to choose which answer (s)he found the *most helpful*. That doesn't necessarily mean the *most correct*. This is what voting is for. I don't understand what the question is here. Just because the asker doesn't understand the answers doesn't mean the question is left unanswered. Anyone can still post an answer.

Comment: @JoseK,this is what I meant.Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, yes that is also there.So we need an attributes in the page to say whether the question is most helpful in this situation.At least that will help person who give answers.

Answer (score 2):

The only person ever to accept an answer as correct or helpful is the person who asked the question. If he/she does not do so, it will never be accepted. After all, it's the only person who can immediately judge if the answer was helpful to him/her.

For the rest of us there are upvotes if we think an answer was particularly good, correct or helpful.